# Can't get background image to show in windows phone pivot grid

Tags: c#, xaml

I can't get background image to show in windows phone pivot grid. Here's the code:

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/BackgroundImage.jpg"/>
        </Grid.Background>
```

I've tried it with the '/' and without e.g.

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="BackgroundImage.jpg"/>
```

and with

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="/BackgroundImage.jpg"/>
```

both show the background image in design view but not in emulator or device. Any help?
(This is for the main app background).

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that property "Build Action" for your image is Content.